# Making ConEmu tab use different network interface (w/ or without ForceBindIP)

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

Suppose we have 2 tabs open in our ConEmu app.

What I want to do is run one of them using the wlan interface wit IP 192.168.1.1 and the other with the wifi dongle interface with the IP adress 192.168.1.2.

How this can be managed?

Comment: Why do you ask about ConEmu at all? ConEmu does not refer to you question.

Comment: I'm sorry Maximus, as you're the developer of ConEmu I thought you would know about running different tabs with some executable like forcebindip but still showing them under the very same window of the ConEmu.

Comment: For example I used to invoke cygwin exe with some special parameters in ssh and it would run flawlessly.

Comment: So, ask the question about cygwin ssh instead.